Cannot Knit in R markdown
I am trying to knit documents in Rstudio. I have had no trouble knitting until now, and everytime I try to knit I get this message.
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string (:4:36)
Execution halted
This appears in every rmarkdown file I have tried to knit (I've tried 5+).
I have already tried reinstalling both R and Rstudio, but get the same problem. I have also tried knitting to pdf and word as well, but get the same error. I can also run code chunk just fine.
EDIT: Adding a Minimal Reproducible Example
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "----"
date: "2024-09-04"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy / pop)
p
```

Trying to knit this results in the aforementioned error message:
"Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string (:4:36)
Execution halted"

Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible question so we can better reproduce the error.

check your .rprofile that you dont have something like setwd('\Users\Stu')

I was able to fix the problem by switching from having no current project to an actual project. Then I clicked "Clear Project List", and knitting worked properly when no project was selected.
